# ajax bar chart y axis showing decimal

Tags: c#

[image]

I want to set ajax bar chart y axis like `1,2,3,4,5....`
Now it showing like  `0.9,1.8,2.7,3.6,4.5.....`
Is there any way?

```
var complaintSummery = bl.GetDailyComplaintSummery().ToList();
string[] x = new string[complaintSummery.Count];
decimal[] y = new decimal[complaintSummery.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < complaintSummery.Count; i++)
{
    x[i] = complaintSummery[i].Date.Day.ToString();
    y[i] = complaintSummery[i].ComplaintCount;
}
BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = y, BarColor = "#d43f3a", Name = "Complaint Count"});
BarChart1.CategoriesAxis = string.Join(",", x);
BarChart1.ChartTitle = string.Format("Daily Complaints");
BarChart1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: **Any Solution??**

Answer (score 0):

Change the values of y axis to int,

```
 int[] y = new int[complaintSummery.Count];
```

Comment: BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = y, BarColor = "#d43f3a", Name = "Complaint Count"});

Comment: "Data = y" Here only Decimal[ ] value supports

Comment: cannot convert source int[] to target decimal[]

Comment: Is there any possible to keep only integers in ASP Ajax chart on y axis please let me know Urgent Iam Struck

Comment: you have team viewer?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] y = new int[complaintSummery.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < complaintSummery.Count; i++)
{
    x[i] = complaintSummery[i].Date.Day.ToString();
    y[i] = Math.Round(complaintSummery[i].ComplaintCount);
}
```

now its only consider the round figure values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!